# how to wrap text with navigation links in swift UI?

Tags: swiftui, text, swiftui-navigationlink

I am getting inconsistent view if i try to add TEXT with navigation link on it. Second text just become double line instead of occupying available space. if try to  remove line limit then text get truncated

[image]

{

```
                            HStack(spacing: 3) {


                                Text(data.createdBy.name)
                                    .font(.subheadline)
                                    .lineLimit(data.mentions == nil ? 1 : nil)
                                    .alignmentGuide(.leading, computeValue: { d in d[.leading] })

                                if let mentionedUsers = data.mentions, mentionedUsers.count > 0 {
                                    NavigationLink(destination: ProfileView(profileId: mentionedUsers[0].id, intent: intent)) {
                                        Text("is with ")
                                            .font(.subheadline)
                                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                                            .lineLimit(nil)
                                            .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)

                                        Text(mentionedUsers[0].name)
                                            .foregroundColor(.blue)
                                            .font(.subheadline)
                                            .lineLimit(nil)
                                            .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                                    }

                                    if mentionedUsers.count > 1 {
                                        Text(" & \(mentionedUsers.count - 1) \(mentionedUsers.count == 2 ? "Other" : "Other(s)")")
                                            .foregroundColor(.blue)
                                            .font(.subheadline)
                                            .lineLimit(nil)
                                            .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                                    }
                                }
                            }


                               
                        }
```

Comment: You cant but you can use URL Scheme or onOpenURL